# create custom control with HTML and Jquery only

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have a tree view created using HTML and Jquery only.

I would like to know can i create a custom control using just HTML and jquery to make it re-usable. If yes then can someone please throw some light on how i can achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you could use a regular asp.net user control and implement everything in the ascx file and doing nothing in the .cs/.vb file. User controls ultimatley render to html controls + javascript anyway :)

Comment: Elad, thanks for the reply. I agree with you that user control is an option for me, but i m exploring ways to make it a custom control. If not i will make user control then

Comment: You can also create the control client-side only in a seperate .js file and include that .js file wherever you want to use the control and asign it to specific div in $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it reusable as an ASP.NET control, it also has to be naming container safe, if you want to be sure it can be safely dropped anywhere, or used more than once on a page. This means you need to be sure that you are passing the script a reference to a unique ID of the root of the control's markup (e.g. the `ClientID`), and any other references are relative to that.

But generally, you can make a custom control self-contained in several ways. If it has no controls, then you could include all the resources (HTML and script) as [embedded resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292). The control can at the simplest level stream its own embedded resources to the client in the `Render` method.

To deal with scripts, you can similarly use `ScriptManager` to register it's own embedded javascript as a client script block. This is not ideal, though, because your script will always be included in a block, and therefore probably not cached very well by the clients.

A better way is to serve embedded resources using `WebResource.axd.` [Here is an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131200/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080906-1.aspx) that explains how to do this.

Personally, I find `WebResource` and embedded resources to be a huge pain in the neck. You need to keep `AssemblyInfo.cs` in sync with the resources, and assembly name & namespace conventions always seem to be impossibly difficult to get correct. I have found it much easier to simply expose a static method of the custom control, e.g.:

```
public static Stream GetEmbeddedResource(someResourceIdentifier, out string mimeType) {
  /// return a stream of my own embedded resource ... can be used for anything
  /// css, js, html
}
```

Then just create your own web handler to use as a resource loader and stream the contents. This is so much easier, and you also don't end up with `WebResource.axd` includes with 200 character long query strings.